# visual studio 2013 local variables not showing in debugger

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution written in VB with some C# components. The solution uses some libraries from 2 outside sources. I have been working on this project for several months without issue. I cannot identify anything specific that I did to change my system or configuration. I was just working through the code, transitioning from an old set of library calls to the new library calls. The new library calls require complete rewrite so I change sections of the code and test to that point. Visual Studio 2013 debugger as of Friday morning will no longer recognize or show my local variables in this solution. The only things that appear in the Locals window are under Me. The code does work and I have it writing out to a text log file to confirm the values of variables at certain points, but the debugger has gone blind. When I add any of these local variables to Watch the response is " is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Steps I've taken so far with no permanent success:

- looked online and tried the few matches I found with no success
- deleted the bin and obj folders and had the solution rebuild with no
  success
- recreated solution from scratch, copied over base files and rebuilt
  solution and project (which worked for a few hours), until I did a
  rebuild project and problem appeared again
- updated to pack 5 and no success

I have opened my older projects and checked them. The debugger runs just fine and shows the variables. It is obviously something that happens during the rebuild process.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Update:
Let me try to explain a little more clearly the situation.

I have an application I have built and am selling to some customers. Version 1 is installed and running at several locations. It is written in VB and uses some older COM libraries for a particular integration process.

The vendor is retiring the COM libraries. Their new libraries are in C#.

I created a new copy of my entire application (solution) and imported the new C# libraries. I have been going through and replacing the old code with the code for the new calls.I recompiled the solution and everything ran fine in debug.

The objects used with the new calls are completely different and there is limited documentation so I update a section of code and test to that point. Each time I "Save all Files", rebuild the project and test the changes. Everything worked fine for a few days. On Friday morning I started working on more changes and got an odd error. The system was not getting a proper value for a certain variable. When I went to check it in the WATCH window, debugger said it could not evaluate it. I figured something was hung up so I shut everything down and rebooted my machine. When I tried it again later, the same problem.

After several hours of no success I exited VS, renamed the folder to "OLD" and recreated the solution from the older version. Immediately everything was looking fine. I started making the changes and testing. Each time I did a rebuild, everything looked fine until the last change. Here I am again.

The code works fine up to the point I have updated. The only issue is that the debugger windows are not working correctly. If a variable is declared at the Class level outside the Sub, they can be seen. The only variables the debugger is blind to are the local variables within the running Sub.

I looked for anyone else with this issue and only found a few items. I tried the suggestions but no joy. I am left with having to temporarily define the variables outside the sub so I can see them while debugging.

I am on VS 2013 Update 5.

Do I need to move to VS 2015 to get around this?

Thanks again for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you haven't changed versions of visual studio since the last time a rebuild worked for you.

```
recreated solution from scratch, copied over base files and rebuilt solution and project (which worked for a few hours), until I did a rebuild project and problem appeared again
```

Based on this, you create it from scratch and everything works until you do the rebuild right? But you are copying the base files still and you have new library calls since the last time a rebuild didn't mess up the locals window. So one of those is almost assuredly the culprit.

Since the library calls seem to be the thing that changed based on your post start there. If you go back to the old code and do a rebuild does it fix it? Assuming so, put the library calls back one at a time until it breaks.

If going back to the old code doesn't fix it, create from scratch with the old code and copy over the base files and rebuild. If that fixes it, add new library calls one at a time and rebuild after each until it breaks.

If that doesn't fix it either, then you will need to dig deeper on what else might have changed.

You are copying base files so eliminate those as the problem if you can:
Are you able to use placeholders instead of the base files or something that won't necessarily work as a finished product but that will allow you to debug, rebuild, debug again to see if the problem is related to one of them? Check the dates on the base files and ensure that they haven't changed since the last time a rebuild worked.

Something you could do concurrently could be to have have a colleague do a rebuild on their machine and see if the same issue comes up for them. It would (almost) completely eliminate the possibility that it is a configuration / program corruption issue on yours. Alternately, there are some free vb.net compilers online that you can upload files and code to. I'm not sure if that would be practical for you (due to the components of your program and/or sensitivity of the data) or not and haven't ever tried any where there is C# code in there but I wouldn't think that would be an issue.